# OSM geometry of real roads instead of nodes and edges

Tags: python, geolocation, openstreetmap, openrouteservice

I'm kind of new to OSM and working with geo data.

I have gps track data from a car (illustrated in red). When overlaying this data with the geometry I got from [open route service](https://openrouteservice.org/) (illustrated in blue), they are a litte bit different, when it comes to turns. The blue line follows the OSM data, while the red line actually is on the road. This way, I cannot really detemine a sort of radius for this turn. This highly depends on the "curvature" of the previous and folloing sections, since if they are very straight, there is no new point for a long time.

Is there a possibility to get the "real" geometry (lines that are actually drivable) of the roads instead of the edges between to nodes? I think of a more dense list of gps points that approximate the road. I basically want to to have a somehow realistic recreation of the real gps data using a service like openrouteservice. Or is this a limitation of the available data in the specific region in general?

Thanks for your help!
PS: I'm working with the python API of ors.

[image]

Comment: maybe try OSRM http://project-osrm.org/